# httpd virtualhost - redirect domains not in the list

Tags: apache, redirect, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I'd like to do a redirect when a subdomain requested is out of scope.
Example of my subdomains:

```
www.vm.com 
client.vm.com 
agent.vm.com 
employee.vm.com 
admin.vm.com
```

VirtualHost block used:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/apache/projects
    ServerName vm.com
    ServerAlias *.vm.com

    ErrorLog logs/vm.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/vm.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

I can't find any negation example, only intentional redirects like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1\.vm\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.vm.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Is it possible to have some kind of syntax like:

```
!(www|client|agent|employee|admin)\.vm\.com
```

Thanks.

Comment: `!` is the standard for negation. `RewriteCond !^donotredirect.vm.com ...`, so yes, that would be doable, just don't forget the `^` to anchor the pattern at the start of the string, otherwise you'd find that `notaclient` and `foowww` would also get rejected.

Comment: `^` - yep, I remember :) the `!^donotredirect.vm.com` would work I quess but it's a single entry, I want to achieve one-liner with `|` joiner